# Finding coordinates

Tags: geometry

6. The slope of the line passing through the point $(5,5)$ is $\dfrac 56$. All of the following points could be on the line except

[image]

A. $(2.5, 2) $

B. $(11, 10) $

C. $(8, 7.5) $

D. $(-1, 0) $

E. $(-7, -5)$

Will I use the slope formula: $\dfrac{y-y_2}{y_-y_1} = \dfrac{x-x_2}{x_-x_1}$? or there are any method to solve this problem quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use slope formula:
$$m=\dfrac {y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$
$$\dfrac 56=\dfrac {y_2-5}{x_2-5}$$
put your options in above equation 
answer is (B)

Comment: You may want to look at the options again:  [B] (11,10) _is_ on the line, but _one_ of the others is not...

Comment: @RecklessReckoner I don't get your point.It is obvious if a point is not satisfies slope equation it means it is not on line.I put every option in above equation and checked it.So what do you want to say?

Comment: It's choice [A] (2.5,2) that is _not_ on the line; it would have to be (2, 2.5).

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the line is $y - 5 = \frac{5}{6}(x-5)$. It can be simplified as $y = \frac{5}{6}(x+1)$, you can substitute each of the coordinate into this line equation.